# Installing Microsoft Exchange 2007 on Windows Web Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

Is it possible to install Microsoft Exchange 2007 on Micorsoft Windows Server 2008 Web Edition?

Answer (score 2):

You can only install Exchange client access on Windows 2008 wed edition; not the store or transfer agents.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719.aspx